# Samba share pointing to a mounted drive on raspberry Pi has no more free space but there's plenty

Tags: mount, samba

I hope this is the right place to get some help as I believe this to be an issue with Samba or more likely my configuration / mount that is used by it.

Short background story: I have a raspberry pi which I use as a media server with Jellyfin. Now of course the space on the SD is limited, hence I wanted to advance the available space by using an old external HDD I have.

The Jellyfin drive is under /media/files/ [ls -l on /media/files] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUUom.png)

There are files already present in Movies and TV Shows. Now I added a new folder "Externe" and mounted the external HDD to it. Permission are set to 777 -R, so it should have no issues with that. When I look drives I do see it as such also:

[df -l; showing the 2TB are basically all free (1% used)] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/uW4za.png)

Now to my SMB config. The path is set to /media/files, hence I'm assuming that the "Externe" folder will also be taken into account.

[SMB.conf] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XK60.png)

I can see the folder from my PC / access it and also for example create a folder or copy a small file, like a pic:

[SMB share open on client PC] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFmTp.png)

But when I now try to copy a larger junk of movies as I intend to do, then I do get the error that there not enough space and some 3,X GBs missing. The files to be copied there are a total of 47,X GBs, so it should be no problem at all.

Copy fails with 47GBs to what is supposed to be nearly 2TB of free space.

Any idea what I am messing up to have this error? It makes no sense to me as the drive is there, it's mounted, I can reach it and even copy / transfer / create files but has only an issue with size, that I cannot explain.

Since I saw a few posts online about having problems with exfat, I changed the drive to ext4 with no luck. Same as above.

Comment: Well I tested a bit more and also searched for it wide and long but could not find the problem. Everything seems to be right tho, as I can simply transfer the files part by part in junks, that simply have to be smaller then these 40-something GBs in total and it will start copy and work. Checking the partition afterwards reveals that it is indeed taken space from the external. So it has to be a visual bug or something. Just posting this for somebody in the future finding this, it might help. Post can otherwise be closed.